# How to import a font from a .ttf file

Tags: c#, string, fonts, graphic, drawstring

I'm using Graphics.DrawString and I don't want to use Arial for my font but I don't know how to use/import one from file. This is my code.

```
using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14))
{
    Graphics.DrawString("Hello", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(2, 2));
}
```

I'm using a .ttf file.

Comment: does the font file have to be in the project map?

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y505zzfw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-6

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation [How to: Create a Private Font Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx) contains a code sample showing how to use the [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) class to load and use a custom font.